# Asignar el tamaño a un vector de tipo char por el numero de elementos que contenga

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria, vectores

Quiero declarar un vector de tipo `char`, la pregunta es de qué manera tengo que hacerlo si quiero que el tamaño proporcional al número de elementos que va a contener.

Nota: los elementos del vector son cadenas de caracteres.

Para los vectores enteros sería algo asi:

```cpp
int vector[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

El vector tendrá como tamaño el número de elementos contenidos en la llave.

La manera en la que intento hacerlo es de la siguiente:

```cpp
char vector[] = {"Esto","es","una","prueba"};
```

Pero me muestra un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Enterado, editare la pregunta para que sea mas clara

Answer (score 4):

Aquí estás declarando un array de enteros, es decir, en cada posición del array se encontrará un número entero:

```
int vector[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

Sin embargo aquí declaras un array de caracteres, es decir, en cada posición del array se debería encontrar un caracter ... pero tu intentas almacenar una cadena de caracteres:

```
char vector[] = {"Esto","es","una","prueba"};
```

La manera correcta de declarar este array sería:

```
char * vector[] = {"Esto","es","una","prueba"};
```

Ahora el compilador esperará encontrar en cada posición del array una cadena de caracteres, que es justamente lo que estás intentando almacenar

Answer (score 3):

**Son dos operaciones distintas**, en la primera con números enteros, estás simplemente intentando almacenar números enteros.

En la segunda, **estás intentado almacenar un array, que a su vez contiene arrays de tipo** `char`. Es decir, esto es un array en si mismo `char vector[] = {"prueba"}`. Por tanto por hacer una analogía con los números enteros, es como si intentas almacenar una matriz en vez de un solo número.

Si quieres almacenar arrays de string (un string es un array de `char`) una de las formas de hacerla es esta:

```
char *vector[] = {"Esto","es","una","prueba"};
```

Aquí lo que estás haciendo es crear un array de punteros tipo char, que apuntan cada uno, a cada palabra.